# trying lasagna plot, getting non numeric operator error

Tags: r

I am trying to make a lasagna plot, but I keep getting the error:

> Error in zlim[1] - zlim[2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I'm not really sure what is going wrong, or if I should be reconfiguring the matrix in some way. I want a lasagna plot with the fips code on the y-axis, the year on the x-axis, and colors based on the numbers. Sample of data and code below:

```
library(devtools)  
install_github("swihart/lasagnar")                                                               
library(fields)
library(lasagnar)   
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(colorspace) 

dput(head(lg1[1:20]))
structure(list(fips = c("36033", "48015", "48039", "48041", "48051", 
"48071"), `1900` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `1901` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), `1903` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1904` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), `1906` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1908` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), `1909` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `1910` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `1911` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1912` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ), `1913` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1915` = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1), `1916` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1917` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), `1918` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1919` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `1920` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1921` = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), `1923` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

lg1 <- as.matrix(lg1)
names(dimnames(lg1))<-c('Location','Year')
lasagna(lg1, gridlines = TRUE, col=rev("virdis"), legend=TRUE, main="")
```

Comment: Check the type of your matrix, as there's a character colmun in data frame, it forces the same type on matrix too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your first column as the row names to get the y-axis labels and make your values numeric. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(fields)
library(lasagnar)   
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(colorspace) 

lg1 <- apply(lg1, 2, as.numeric)
lg1 <- as.matrix(lg1)
rownames(lg1) <- lg1[,1]
lg1 <- lg1[,-1]
names(dimnames(lg1))<-c('Location','Year')
par(mai = c(.34,.7,.04,.09))
lasagna(lg1, gridlines = TRUE, main="")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. Follow up: what does par(mai  = c()) do?

Comment: Hi @tchoup, that is to adjust the plot window size, to make sure that the labels are visable. For more info check ?par.